# Android Universal Image Loader and image persistence

Tags: android, android-asynctask, download, universal-image-loader

I'm currently downloading and save some pictures in my Android app.

**Here is the class which do the work :**

```
public class BitmapPersist extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

private ArrayList<String> photosNotDownloaded;
private File pointDir;
private KickstartrGeolocPoint point;
private OnBitmapPersistedListener onBitmapPersistedListener;

public BitmapPersist(ArrayList<String> photosNotDownloaded, File pointDir, KickstartrGeolocPoint point, OnBitmapPersistedListener onBitmapPersistedListener) {
    this.photosNotDownloaded=photosNotDownloaded;
    this.pointDir=pointDir;
    this.point=point;
    this.onBitmapPersistedListener=onBitmapPersistedListener;
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    Bitmap bmp;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    for(String url : photosNotDownloaded) {

        //download the picture synchronously
        bmp = ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImageSync(url);

        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(pointDir.getPath() + File.separator + FileUtils.getPointPhotoPrefix(point) + FileUtils.getFileNameFromUrl(url));
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (Throwable ignore) {
            }
        }

        //send notification to the UI in order to scan again the directory and update the carousel
        publishProgress();
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
    if (success)
        onBitmapPersistedListener.persistedSuccessfully(this.point, this.pointDir);
    else
        onBitmapPersistedListener.errorInPersistance();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    onBitmapPersistedListener.onProgress();
}
}
```

This class take an ArrayList of urls in parameter, and for each photo, it download it and save it.
Each time a photo is persisted, a notification is sent to the view to update a carousel (thanks to publishProgress(); )
The problem is that publishProgress() does not work, and every photos are displayed at the same time when every photos are downloaded.

**Here is the call of my asynctask :**

```
 private void persistImageforPoint(ArrayList<String> photosNotDownloaded, KickstartrGeolocPoint point, File pointDir) {
    // Create a subfolder for each point with its id
    if (!pointDir.exists()) {
        if (!pointDir.mkdirs()) {
            LogWrapper.debug(FileUtils.class, "Failed to create directory");
            return;
        }
    }

    //save the file. Asynchronous task --> do not block the UI
    new BitmapPersist(photosNotDownloaded, pointDir, point, new OnBitmapPersistedListener() {

        @Override
        public void persistedSuccessfully(KickstartrGeolocPoint point, File pointDir) {
            if(currentPoint!=null) {
                File pointDirectory = FileUtils.getPointPhotoDir(getActivity(), currentPoint);
                loadCarousel(currentPoint, pointDirectory);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void errorInPersistance() {
            LogWrapper.error(getClass(),"Error persisting image");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgress() {
            if(currentPoint!=null) {
                final File pointDir = FileUtils.getPointPhotoDir(getActivity(), currentPoint);
                loadCarousel(currentPoint, pointDir);
            }
        }
    }).execute();
}
```

I don't have any errors in my logcat.

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Add a log at `onProgress`, is it ever called? maybe the `currentPoint` is null?

Comment: I did'nt think to add a log here... yes, onprogress is called each time a photo is downloaded.. would it means that I have a problem when I try to update the carousel ? Probably...